# day formula in a if statement

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am using the formula below to check to see if January first is on Saturday. The calendar I've created will flip years using a macro in place, so January first may not always lay on a Saturday. The reason I need to use DAY is because the cell it is refering to is in a DAY format.

=IF(DAY(H5)=1,"Winter","") [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPX9z.jpg)

January 1st Days of the week

2018- Monday [Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T600p.jpg)

2019- Tuesday

2023- Saturday etc...

So H5 is the place of the first Saturday in January,

if H5 = January 1st it should show "Winter" if not it should return blank. The issue is the formula is getting caught on the DAY(H5)=1. It returns #Value instead of a blank.  Is there a work around I can use to show blanks instead?

I have conditional formatting in place so the cell is grayed out (Font colour and Fill). It looks good when it's in the spreadsheet but once it it is printed it will still show #VALUE.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the formula in a IFERROR():

```
=IFERROR(IF(DAY(H5)=1,"Winter",""),"")
```

Or you can test to ensure the H5 has a value:

```
=IF(H5<>"",IF(DAY(H5)=1,"Winter",""),"")
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! Works great

Comment: @JasonMichaud please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.